# How to Subtract n numbers using for loop in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, exception, subtraction

When I use for loop for subtraction, i don't get a correct output.

What logic should i apply in my code to get my subtraction correctly using for loop?

Please help me as i am new in JAVA.

My code is as Follow:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Sub
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,n,i;
        String yn;
        boolean loop=true;

        while(loop)
        {
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    loop=true;
                    System.out.println("Enter how many numbers to Subtract?: ");
                    n=s.nextInt();
                    int sum=0;
                    for(i=1;i<=n;)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            System.out.println("Enter number "+i+" : ");
                            a=s.nextInt();
                            sum=a-sum;
                            i++;
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Try again!!");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Answer is:"+sum);
                    System.out.println("Do you want to continue?(Y/N): ");
                    yn=s.next();
                    loop=yn.equals("Y")||yn.equals("y");
                }while(loop);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Re-enter the Limit");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably get the first value and make that the `sum` value and then loop through the remaining values...

Comment: Probably the problem is @ this statemeent: sum=a-sum; I really don't understand what is the purpose of it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer-OP has also done things not different to your thought,but,with a slight complication because `sum=0` and `sum=a-sum`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with `sum` as the first number (not zero) and subtract the rest of the numbers from it:

```
    loop=true;
    System.out.println("Enter how many numbers to Subtract?");
    n=s.nextInt();
    int sum=0;
    for(i=1;i<=n;)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Enter number "+i+" : ");
            a=s.nextInt();
            sum=a-sum;
            i++;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Try again!!");
        }
    }
```

to:

```
...
loop = true;
System.out.println("Enter how many numbers to Subtract?: ");
n = s.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter number 1 : ");
int sum = s.nextInt();
for (int i=2; i <= n; i++) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter number " + i + " : ");
        a = s.nextInt();
        sum -= a;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Try again!!");
    }
}
...
```

Further, instead of doing:

```
yn.equals("Y") || yn.equals("y")
```

you can use `equalsIgnoreCase()`:

```
yn.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")
```

And last, you should use meaningful names for variables (it's recommended to develop good habits even if it's such a small program), so instead of:

```
    int a, n, i; // you can define and use i inside the for-loop - no need to define it outside
    String yn;
```

consider using more expressive names, such as:

```
    int inputNumber, numberOfVariables;
    String continueLooping;
```

---

The following version could be improved (refactored even further):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        int numOfArguments = getNumberOfArguments(scanner);
        int sum = getNextNumberFromUser(scanner, 1);
        for (int i = 2; i <= numOfArguments; i++) {
            sum -= getNextNumberFromUser(scanner, i);
        }
        System.out.println("Answer is: " + sum + "\n\nDo you want to continue?(Y/N): ");
        String runAgain = scanner.next();
        if (runAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

private static int getNextNumberFromUser(Scanner scanner, int i) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter number " + i + " : ");
            return scanner.nextInt();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry. Try again!!");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
}

private static int getNumberOfArguments(Scanner scanner) {
    int numberOfArguments = -1;
    System.out.println("Enter how many numbers to Subtract?: ");
    while (numberOfArguments == -1) {
        try {
            numberOfArguments = scanner.nextInt();
            if (numberOfArguments <= 0) {
                numberOfArguments = -1;
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Illegal number of arguments to subtract, please try again: ");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
    return numberOfArguments;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. I will keep in mind these points henceforth.

Comment: But if i eneter the first number as string it should again ask to enter the first number and then continue to the next step. Please help

Comment: @MohammedRampurawala that's why we initiate `i` inside the for-loop to start from 2: `for (int i=2; i <= n; i++)`.

Comment: I understood that part. But i want exception to be handled when i enter the first number wrong,i.e"Enter number 1: q", it should throw an exception and again ask the user to enter the first number.

Comment: @MohammedRampurawala check out the last part of the answer. Pay attention to the way the original `main()` was broken down and two methods were extracted out of it. Reading the code now has become easier because it's written "top-down" which means: the reader can understand what's going on by just reading the `main()` - and keep on going only if the reader is interested in the smaller details of the implementation. If you'll get this approach and adopt it - you'll gain much much more than getting this task done. Good luck!

Comment: I m so sorry i didnt see the last part. It Worked well. Thank you very much